# Google App Engine: how can I programmatically access the properties of my Model class?

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine

I have a model class:

```
class Person(db.Model):
  first_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  last_name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I have an instance of this class in `p`, and string `s` contains the value `'first_name'`. I would like to do something like:

```
print p[s]
```

and

```
p[s] = new_value
```

Both of which result in a `TypeError`.

Does anybody know how I can achieve what I would like?

Comment: What does `dir(p)` show?

Answer (score 7):

If the model class is sufficiently intelligent, it should recognize the standard Python ways of doing this.

Try:

```
getattr(p, s)
setattr(p, s, new_value)
```

There is also hasattr available.

Comment: Dave, is it possible there is a difference between the db.Model and db.Expando classes?

Answer (score 3):

With much thanks to Jim, the exact solution I was looking for is:

```
p.properties()[s].get_value_for_datastore(p)
```

To all the other respondents, thank you for your help. I also would have expected the Model class to implement the python standard way of doing this, but for whatever reason, it doesn't.

Comment: Why use get_value_for_datastore? If you want the same representation you'd get from p.first_name, you shouldn't be calling that.

Comment: what about the second part of your question? What about p[s] = new_val?

Answer (score 1):

```
getattr(p, s)
setattr(p, s, new_value)
```

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for you reply. The above code results in an AttributeError.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
p.model_properties()[s].get_value_for_datastore(p)
```

See [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_get_value_for_datastore).

Comment: Would that even work? model_properties is a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the correct path. The exact answer is p.properties()[s].get_value_for_datastore(p)

Answer (score -1):

p.first_name = "New first name"
p.put()

or p = Person(first_name = "Firsty",
              last_name = "Lasty" )
p.put()