# How to write data by dynamic parameter name

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to be able to write data to datastore of google-app-engine for some known entity. But I don't want write assignment code for each parameter of the entity. I meen, I don't want do like this

```
val_1 = self.request.get('prop_1')
val_2 = self.request.get('prop_2')
...
val_N = self.request.get('prop_N')
item.prop_1 = val_1
item.prop_2 = val_2
...
item.prop_N = val_N
item.put()
```

instead, I want to do something like this

```
args = self.request.arguments()
  for prop_name in args:
    item.set(prop_name, self.request.get(prop_name))
item.put()
```

dose anybody know how to do this trick?

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91821/google-app-engine-how-can-i-programmatically-access-the-properties-of-my-model) is similar to mine but it seems that this guy wants only to read data. I need to write!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746942/adding-a-user-supplied-property-at-runtime-to-an-instance-of-expando-class-in

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Expando](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html) class.

> The Expando class is a superclass for data model definitions whose
>   properties are determined dynamically. An Expando model can have a
>   combination of fixed properties similar to Model and dynamic
>   properties assigned to an entity at run-time

Comment: thank you, but it is not for my case. In my case, prop_name is string that I take from *request* object and I don't see a method to use it in Expando too.

Comment: @MaximWelikobratov item.setattr(name, value) should do the trick, but the item needs to be an expando.

Comment: It seems that Expando dose not have setattr. I can't find description of this method and it say my fast tests *"AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'setattr'"*

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746942/adding-a-user-supplied-property-at-runtime-to-an-instance-of-expando-class-in

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `exec`, but I would not recommend it at all. Please consider the security implications involved with this. eg. the possibility that a user posts a new key for your object thus potentially hijacking the object.

If you must do it, however, the `exec` method would definitely help you, as [described here](http://techblog.ironfroggy.com/2007/06/dynamic-hell.html) (the link also contains more reasons why this is probably not a good idea).

Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: This is a spectacularly bad idea, especially since Python has built-in  mechanisms for setting properties and attributes at runtime.