# Return object property value for variable property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am trying to set up a debugging page with a list of objects, object property names, and object property values. I am trying to obtain the value of an particular property of a particular object type. Neither the object type or the property are know when I'm coding.

Here are the relevant sections I've got so for:

In my test.py

```
if self.request.get('objID'):
  qGet = self.request.get
  thisObj = db.get(db.Key(qGet('objID')))

template_values = { 'thisObj' : thisObj }

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('objProp.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

and in my objProp.html template

```
{% if thisObj %}
  <ul>List of properties
  {% for p in thisObj.properties() %}
    <li>{{ p }} : {{ thisObj.p }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

However since there is no property p in thisObj it always prints out a null value, really what I want so to print out the value of whatever property p is referring to at that particular point in the loop

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach that I got working. I'm not going to accept it, because I'm not sold on it being a 'good' approach yet.

See also: [Google App Engine: how can I programmatically access the properties of my Model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91821/google-app-engine-how-can-i-programmatically-access-the-properties-of-my-model)

That question got me most of the way there, here is what I'm using and it appears to be functioning correctly:

```
{% if thisObj %}
  <ul>List of properties
  {% for p in thisObj.properties() %}
    <li>{{ p }} : {{ thisObj.properties()[p].get_value_for_datastore(thisObj) }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

It seems like p is resolving as a string, `thisObj.properties()[p]` is returning the object property, then I just need to get the value out of that object with `.get_value_for_datastore(thisObj)`

Referenced from documentation here: [The Property Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass#Property_get_value_for_datastore)

Comment: You could avoid the [p] step by using `thisObj.properties().values()` and then use `p.get_value_for_datastore(thisObj)`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `thisObj.p`  as you are not looking up the name in `thisObj`. `.p` in this instance is not the p from the loop, but trying to refer to a property or method called "p".

You should use

`getattr(thisObj,p)`

Comment: I'm getting an indication that getattr() is undefined. Is there some way to enable this function in a Jinja template?

Comment: The other answer is the better one, and works. I don't use jinja so I don't know why don't have access to getattr